# count items in a column using pandas

Tags: pandas, string, split, expand

A csv file from a DDBB. Some rows in a column have over a item. I would like to count every item in every rows in a column

for example; a line in a column has four items:

```
column1, column2, column3, column4
aaa, bbb,ccc,ddd ddd ddd ddd, eee
bbb, ccc,eee, ddd, eee
fff, ccc, eee,ddd, eee
```

`df["column3"].value_counts()`  must be 6

`df["column3"].str.split('\n', expand=True)` not work

Comment: Can you add your expected output?

Comment: count values in "column3" == 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After splitting you can sum the lengths of the results:

```
>>> df.column3.str.split().str.len().sum()
6
```

Alternatively, summing the count of whitespaces (plus 1) without splitting:

```
>>> df.column3.str.count("\s+").add(1).sum()
6
```

---

Doing this for every column:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda s: s.str.count("\s+").add(1).sum())

column1    3
column2    3
column3    6
column4    3
```